# Using JSON Arrays in Select Options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a select box where the options follow this format:

```
 <select id="acctg_dept" name="acctg_dept">
    <option value="{'acctg_dept_nbr':'2','acctg_dept_desc':'ELECTRONICS'}">02 - ELECTRONICS</option>
   ...
</select>
```

I am trying to pass two values via ajax like so. I've tried with and without declaring the `acctg_dept` as array.

```
var acctg_dept = [];
  acctg_dept = $('#acctg_dept').val();
  $.ajax({
    type : 'post',        
    url : url,
    data : {acctg_dept: JSON.stringify(acctg_dept)},        
    dataType : "data",
  ...
```

Right now I have stringify there, but have tried it without and am still having problems..

The ajax calls a PHP page that does this:

`$acctg_dept = $_REQUEST['acctg_dept'];
 $acctg_dept = json_decode("$acctg_dept",true);`

Again, I've tried this a few different ways and still am not getting the result I am looking for which is being able to do the following in the same PHP script.

`$acctg_dept_nbr = $acctg_dept['acctg_dept_nbr'];`

Using the method outlined here I get illegal string offset. I've tried foreach and `$acctg_dept[0]['acctg_dept_nbr'];` and am getting nowhere. I figure PHP doesn't see it as an array, but I am not sure why not.

Comment: `acctg_dept` should already be a string, you don't need to call `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: install firebug and monitor the ajax call to see where the problem is

Comment: When I do that the illegal offset error goes away, but the `$acct_dept_nbr = $acctg_dept['acctg_dept_nbr'];` assignment still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Tried this?
`value="<?php echo htmlentities("{'acctg_dept_nbr':'2','acctg_dept_desc':'ELECTRONICS'}"); ?>"`

Comment: @AnthonyGrist you need to stringify it if you want it to be interpreted as a JSON, otherwise you will have a parser reader exception on "server" side..

Comment: @LMG There's nothing to stringify, it's not a JavaScript object or array, it's **already a string**.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yes! sorry man, you are right!

Comment: Your string is invalid JSON so it will never work. Identifiers and values should be quoted with double quotes not single. Avoid manually building JSON. In PHP use `json_encode()` on a native array or object.

Comment: The select box is being built through a js script based on selections in other select boxes.

When I pass the value in $acctg_dept_nbr it returns [];

Comment: I got it. I think it was actually MrCode's solution that did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it but not tested..

html code

```
<select id="acctg_dept" name="acctg_dept">
 <option  value='{"acctg_dept_nbr":"2","acctg_dept_desc":"ELECTRONICS"}'>ELC</option>  
</select>
```

ajax call to your server php file

```
var acctg_dept = [];
acctg_dept = $('#acctg_dept').val();
$.ajax({
 type : 'post',        
 url : url,
 data : {acctg_dept: acctg_dept},     //don't stringify it   
  success:function(data){
  console.log(data);
 }
});
```

on server side try to catch post data

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
die;
```